# Calling power bi dashboard from c#

Tags: .net, winforms, powerbi

I have requirement to create a rich ui dashboard dynamically based on user input. Can i call power bi dashboard from my Windows form application ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [example](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/integrate-power-bi-dashboards-reports-and-tiles-into-a-wpf-application/) how to do this in WPF application, but the only difference is that `InvokeScript` method in WPF is in WebBrowser itself, while in WinForms it is in `WebBrowser.Document`. This example shows how to embed Power BI elements in a native desktop application (WPF, WinForms, etc).

First you need to know that there are two modes for embedding Power BI - `user owns data` and `app owns data`. With the first mode, when embedding, the user will authenticate itself using it's own Power BI Pro account, i.e. each of your users needs Power BI Pro license. With the later one, you need only one "master account", which will be used for authentication. The differences in the implementation aren't tremendous, so I will describe `app owns data`.

You need to do the following:

- Register an application - go to [dev.powerbi.com/apps](https://dev.powerbi.com/apps) and register a native application. Select which permissions to grant it (if you aren't sure, for your first tests simply grant them all). Copy the guid - this is the app ID, a.k.a. client ID.
- Next step is to authenticate from your application and get an access token. Use [Azure Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) for that - call some of the `acquireToken` methods of `AuthenticationContext` class.
- Use this access token to call the Power BI REST API and get the `embedUrl` of the element you want to embed, e.g. [report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/getreportingroup#report).
- Use [Power BI JavaScript client](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embedding-Basics) to actually embed this element. You need to initialize one [embed configuration class](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-Configuration-Details) and pass information about element type (report, dashboard, tile), where to find it (embedUrl), authentication (access token), some other configuration options (show or hide filters pane, navigation, etc.), filters to be applied and so on. In case you will use the access token acquired above, set `tokenType` to be `AAD`. This token has many privileges, so for security reasons you may want to use `Embed` token instead. In this case use the access token to call the REST API again (e.g. [Reports GenerateTokenInGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embedtoken/reports_generatetokeningroup)).
- Call `powerbi.embed` method of the JavaScript client pass the embedded configuration to visualize this Power BI element in your app.

Comment: Is it possible to pass data for dashboard from .net app ?

Comment: No, this isn't possible. But depending on what you want to achieve, you may want to take a look how to [filter it](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Filters).

Comment: Clicking on dev.powerbi.com/apps and then logging in take me to https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/developers/ . And when I pate back dev.powerbi.com/apps it takes me to my home page. Is there any other way of registering App?

Comment: @Gulfam From Azure Portal, go to Azure Active Directory -> App registrations (the URL should be [this one](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/RegisteredApps)).